# Check for date object with Angular Unit Tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

If my expected result is a date object in the following format, how can I test for it?

> Thu Jan 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Daylight Time)

I've tried

```
    expect(theDate).toEqual( Date(Thu Jan 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Daylight Time) ) );
```

But I'm getting the following error on running the test :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

There are no other unclosed brackets casuing the problem. For example, if I change my tests to this:

```
    expect(theDate).toEqual( 'Thu Jan 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Daylight Time)' );
```

It correctly fails with:

> Expected Date(Thu Jan 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)) to equal 'Thu Jan 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Daylight Time)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript Date Object needs to receive a string in the constructor and you need a `new` in front of Date.

```
expect(theDate).toEqual( new Date("Thu Jan 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Daylight Time)") );
```

If you are unsure, you can always extract the compare value and output it for debugging.

```
var expectedDate = new Date("Thu Jan 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Daylight Time)");
console.log('why am I doing it wrong?', theDate, expectedDate);
// expect(theDate).toEqual(expectedDate);
```

Comment: You were right! Ialso needed to add `new` before `Date`. Working now. Thanks.